# sending date as parameter from JSP to servlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

How do I send a date type as a parameter from JSP to servlet so as to insert to MySQL database. When I use getParameter() in the servlet, it shows that I'm using incompartible types. Actually I declared a variable of java.sql.Date type which I assign to the request parameter in the servlet but I get an error that the types are incompartible. I'm trying to submit date from JSP via servlet to MySQL. How is the parameter sent and received in such a case?

Comment: Parameters will be sent as Strings, maybe you need to do some conversion.  Adding some code would help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Pass it as `String` and parse it to server using `SimpleDateFormat` to get the `Date` back

For example:

```
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy").parse("10-10-2010");
```

Comment: Thank you @Joshi. How do I parse using SimpleDateFormat? For example I get the string in this way: `request.getParamater("date")`. How do I convert that back to Date using SimpleDateFormat?

Comment: ok. let me give it a try now and will let you know. I'm sure it's going to work.

Comment: It's done @Joshi. I converted to `java.util.Date` format using `SimpleDateFormat` like you've shown and then further converted to `sql.Date` format using `java.sql.Date date3 = new java.sql.Date(date2.getTime());`: where date2 is the util.Date date. Thank you very much.